# Set controller and controllerAs to the same string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller

Say you have an AngularJS directive in which you want to set the *controller* attribute and the *controllerAs* attribute to the same string.

Ex.

```
angular.module('blahModule', [])
.directive('blahDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'blahController',
        controllerAs: 'blahController',
        templateUrl: 'blah/blah.html'
    }
});
```

The above is valid and works, but it feels redundant to when setting the *controller* and *controllerAs* value to the same thing.  Is there way to do it in one attribute? Like:

```
angular.module('blahModule', [])
.directive('blahDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAndControllerAs: 'blahController',
        templateUrl: 'blah/blah.html'
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
controller: 'blahController as blahController',
```